PyAutoGUI on a headless server
I'm writing a script to automate a process that requires controlling the mouse and keyboard.
I need to run it on a headless vm in Google Cloud.
Can I use PyAutoGUI without display? When I tried it, I got an exception as soon as I dosconnected the RDP.
The OS is Windows, as I require BlueStacks which is most compatible with Windows.
